# Read out last X letters from the right via MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a varchar field that contains a description with variable lenght. I want to read the 4th last letters from the right.

For example if the table contained:

```
|col1 |
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE |
|20161512_NL_Premium_2_DE |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE|
```

I want a query that will return:

```
|result|
+------+
|1     |
|2     |
|4     |
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` seems like it would be a good fit for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '_', -2), '_', 1);
```

See the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for more info on usage.

Essentially, the *inner* call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is finding the second to last `_` character and returns everything to the *right* of it. The *outer* `SUBSTRING_INDEX` call is then finding the first `_` from this result and returning everything up until that point.